# What does this mean in Access?

Tags: ms-access

```
Forms![HiddenUserCheck]![txtStatus]
```

It appears that there is a form called HiddenUserCheck and there is a textfield called txtStatus

But what do the ! mean between the words?

The actual code is

```
If Forms![HiddenUserCheck]![txtStatus] = "Sign In" Then
```

When I debug it and mouse over the words, it says Null

Comment: It's the explicit reference, like the period in c# or the -> in borland c++. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223116(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`!` is used to reference one member of a collection ... `CollectionName!MemberName`

`Forms` is the name of a collection whose members are `Form` objects, and includes those forms which are currently open in your Access session.

A `Form` has a collection of `Control` objects.  So appending `!ControlName` to the form reference gets you a reference to that control.

So `Forms![HiddenUserCheck]![txtStatus]` refers to a control named *txtStatus* in a form named *HiddenUserCheck* which is open in your Access session.

What you get from that reference is the control's default property, `Value` ... the value contained in that control.

Answer (score 2):

One of the hardest things "n00bs" have with Access is trying to determine when to use the bang (!) and when to use the dot (.).  Take a look at [this blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2008/05/30/dot-or-bang.aspx) for some tips.  One solid guide is this: If the object exists, use a dot.  If the object is user-created, use the bang.

So:

```
Forms![HiddenUserCheck]![txtStatus]
```

and:

```
Forms![HiddenUserCheck]![txtStatus].Text
```

Note: "Text" exists in Access, and so is preceded by a dot.  HiddenUserCheck and txtStatus are user-created words, and so are preceded by a bang.

Answer (score 0):

Forms refers to the collection of all forms, HiddenUserCheck is a form in the group of all forms, and txtStatus is a field on HiddenUserCheck form.  The !s are a way of seperating that info out. Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtStatus equates to "The txtStatus field in the form HiddenUserCheck in the collection of all forms.  !